# Unable to Get Username loggedin name from intranet in php

Tags: php, ldap

I want to pass username directly to the ldap without user interaction.
 I am able to get clients hostname,ip address,but i am unble to get user profilename(username) from intranet in php, help me to get username

```
function checkingLogin($username, $pass, $domain) {

    $dom = "$domain\\"; //Domain Prefix for UNAME which ouputs "domain\"
    $user = $dom . $u; 
    $hostname = 'ldap://abc.com';
    $baseDN = 'OU=users, DC=abc, DC=com'; //Narrow down if you have alot of objects as search could take along time
    $search = "(samaccountname=$u)"; //Compare with Username

    $ldap = ldap_connect($hostname);

    if ($ldap) {

        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap, $user, $pass);

        if ($ldapbind) {

            $ldapSearch = ldap_search($ldap, $baseDN, $search);
            $entry = ldap_first_entry($ldap, $ldapSearch);
            $info = ldap_get_values($ldap, $entry, "displayname"); 

            return $info[0];

        }

        return false; //Failed Auth

    } 

      return false; //Connection Failed

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The users browser doesn't provide that information due to security considerations. Otherwise that would mean that the username you use to log into your machine would be sent to *every single website*. Do you really want that?

Besides that, it would need a very tight integration between the computer and the browser. That could be possible with f.e. Windows and Edge or IE but I'd doubt that that works on Firefox or Chrome.

There are ways though to actually do what you want to do. But they require access to the client-machines and a well-known environment. Then you might be able to setup something like Kerberos to allow logging into your computer and use that token to also authenticate against webservices. But that is not a default setup!